# Could not autowire field: javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: java, spring

I created Spring security project connect mysql to authentication

I have 2 class:

**SpringWebConfig.java:**

```
@EnableWebMvc
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan({ "com.tructran.web" })
    @Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
    public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }

        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return viewResolver;
        }

        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/edc_new");
            driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("truc.tran");
            driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("652606");
                return driverManagerDataSource;
            }

        }
```

**SecurityConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN)").and().formLogin();
    }
```

**When I run project It has error:**

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.sql.DataSource com.tructran.config.SecurityConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
        ... 22 more
```

Please help me!!!

Thanks so much :)

Comment: return `DataSource` here: `public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {` ---> `public DataSource dataSource() {`

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your bean creation. This `DriverManagerDataSource` is not a javax.sql.DataSource, as can see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html). Change the implementation for this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/edc_new");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("truc.tran");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("652606");
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {

}
```

Change the result type to:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() {

}
```

Comment: It's still not success. Can you have another way ?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })` and make sure that the package of `SecurityConfig` is listed in `@ComponentScan`

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error and solve it by adding the following dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```